# php.iniでアクセスログの出力先を変更したい

Tags: php, apache

このサイト及びapache初心者ですので、間違い等ございましたらご指摘いただけますと幸いです。

現在php.iniに下記の設定を行っております。(必要な部分のみ抜粋)

```
[Log settings]
error_reporting = "E_ALL"
display_errors = "On"
log_errors = "On"
```

apacheのエラーログの出力先を指定したい場合は上記に`error_log=`でディレクトリを指定すればよいというのは把握しているのですが、通常のアクセスログのディレクトリ指定方法が分からずにいます。
自分なりに調べてみたものの`httpd.conf`の`CustomLog "○○/□□" combined`で指定する等、別のファイルを触る方法しか見つけられておりません。

`php.ini`一つでアクセスログとエラーログの二つをディレクトリ指定をしたいと考えているのですが、
上記件について、何か方法がございましたらご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: Apache のログは Apache 側での設定で調整すべきかと思いますが違いますか？ OS やディストリビューションによって多少異なりますが、`/var/log/httpd` 以下に `access_log` と `error_log` とで分かれている気がします。

Comment: ログ対象はエラー関連だけで、アクセスログの機能は無さそうですね。[実行時設定](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/errorfunc.configuration.php), [どこで設定を行うのか](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/configuration.changes.modes.php). [PHP php.iniの確認と設定](https://www.flying-h.co.jp/media/2022/11/11/php-php-ini-settings/), [PHPの標準ログ出力機能を詳しく解説](https://webukatu.com/wordpress/blog/37092/)

Answer (score 0):

rsyslog をインストールする

php.ini

```
error_log = syslog
syslog.facility = local2
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local.2.info -t httpd_access" combined
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local.2.info -t error"
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
TransferLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local.2.info -t ssl_access"
ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local.2.info -t ssl_error"
```

/etc/rsyslog.d/php.conf

```
local2.* /var/log/php.log
```